# Is there are any way to tell which files are pending to be deleted or renamed on Windows system reboot?

Tags: windows, perl, powershell

Does anyone knows the way to tell which files are going to be deleted or modified on system reboot? Like when you update your system, the system ask to be rebooted because some files are blocked by the system and they need to be replaced or modified. I need to make a script that tells me which file are going to be deleted or modified on startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states:

> #### Remarks
>
> If the `dwFlags` parameter specifies `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT`, [MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) fails if it cannot access the registry. The function stores the locations of the files to be renamed at restart in the following registry value:
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations`
>
> This registry value is of type `REG_MULTI_SZ`. Each rename operation stores one of the following NULL-terminated strings, depending on whether the rename is a delete or not:
>
> - `szDstFile\0\0`
> - `szSrcFile\0szDstFile\0`
>
> The string `szDstFile\0\0` indicates that the file `szDstFile` is to be deleted on reboot. The string `szSrcFile\0szDstFile\0` indicates that `szSrcFile` is to be renamed `szDstFile` on reboot.

You can use [Win32::TieRegistry](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::TieRegistry) to query the Windows registry:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Const::Fast;
use Win32::TieRegistry;
use YAML;

const my $REG_DELIMITER => '/';

$Registry->Delimiter($REG_DELIMITER);

my $key = join $REG_DELIMITER, qw(
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
    SYSTEM
    CurrentControlSet
    Control
    Session Manager
    PendingFileRenameOperations
);

print Dump $Registry->{$key}
```

Comment: I deleted a few application from my system view Windows Uninstall, this is what i got from the KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations registry value:

\??\C:\Users\lurraca\AppData\Local\Temp\~nsu.tmp\Au_.exe

\??\C:\Users\lurraca\AppData\Local\Temp\~nsu.tmp

\??\C:\Users\lurraca\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\DropboxExt64.14.dll

\??\C:\Users\lurraca\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\

\??\C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ACTIVE_X

\??\C:\ProgramData\Adobe\Setup\{AC76BA86-7AD7-1033-7B44-AA1000000001}

Comment: Please update the body of your post showing the exact output from the `Dump`. It is far too hard to read this. Also, note that the embedded `\0`s might interfere with printing so it is essential to see the `Dump` or `Dumper` output. But, AFAICS, everything worked properly.

Comment: I'm getting this msg when i run it with Perl.
Can't locate Const/Fast.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at pending.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at pending.pl line 4.

Answer (score 0):

While this was answered long ago with a Perl script, I would like to offer a PowerShell solution here as it's native to Windows, and the question is tagged as [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell).

We need to query `PendingFileRenameOperations` from the `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager` registry key. I have the following function which queries this registry value and returns an idiomatic PowerShell object you can operate on (compatible with **Windows PowerShell** and **PowerShell Core**):

```
Function Get-PendingFileRenameOperations {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param()

  # Define Registry Variables
  $multiSzPrefix = '^\\\?\?\\'
  $pendingRebootRegPath = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager'

  # Get the PendingFileRenameOperations value as an array of strings
  Write-Verbose "Reading PendingFileRenameOperations from ${pendingRebootRegPath}"
  $pendingFiles = @( Get-ItemProperty $pendingRebootRegPath ).PendingFileRenameOperations
  Write-Verbose "Found $($pendingFiles.Count / 2) PendingFileRenameOperations$([System.Environment]::NewLine)"

  # Loop over each line from PendingFileRenameOperations
  for( $i = 0; $i -lt $pendingFiles.Count; $i++ ) {

    # Get the source file
    $src = $pendingFiles[$i] -replace $multiSzPrefix
    if( !$src ) {

      # Better safe than sorry
      throw [System.InvalidOperationException]::new("${pendingRebootRegPath}\PendingFileRenameOperations is malformed, expected source but got nothing")
    }
    Write-Verbose "Found source: ${src}"

    # Get the target path
    $dst = $pendingFiles[++$i] -replace $multiSzPrefix
    if( $dst ) {
      Write-Verbose "Found target: ${dst}"
    }

    # Determine whether it's a "move" or "delete"
    $operation = if( $dst ) {
      "Move"
    } else {
      "Delete"
    }
    Write-Verbose "Operation: ${operation}$([System.Environment]::NewLine)"

    # Prepare object and return
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      Source = $src
      Target = $dst
      Operation = $operation
    }

    Remove-Variable src, dst, operation
  }
}
```

---

### How it works

- `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager` is the parent key containing the `REG_SZ_MULTI` (multi-line string) with the staged paths for rename. Even lines (zero-indexed) are source files and odd lines are target paths.
- We can use `Get-ItemProperty` to get the registry values under the **Session Manager** key above, and we can then reference the `PendingFileRenameOperations` property on the returned collection of values.
- Each line represents a file path prefixed with the string `\??\`. We need to remove this eventually from the returned path, so the regex pattern to match on is `^\\\?\?\\`. See [RegExr](http://regexr.com/65bbq) for more information about the expression itself.
- Each operation is going to be two lines long. As mentioned, even lines starting with `0` are the `source` file and the odd lines will be the `target` path to move to.
- An *empty* `target` line signifies no target path. This means that the "move" operation is actually going to **delete** the source file on reboot.

  - I don't know if a `source` line can ever be empty for any reason, or if it's safe to skip, so this function errs with caution and bails if the expected `source` line is ever empty.

Now that we understand how the registry key works and how to obtain the data, we can look at the loop logic.

- We loop over each line from `PendingFileRenameOperations`, incrementing the index when we reference the next index used for the `target` line. Essentially, we end up counting through the loop by 2 on each iteration.
- Once we remove the prefix from both the `source` and `target`, we determine whether it's a **Move** or **Delete** `operation` based on whether `$dst` evaluates to false.
- Create a hashtable with the `Source`, `Target`, and `Operation` keys, convert it to a `PSCustomObject`, and output the object to the pipeline. This is easier than establishing `@{}` and piping it to `Add-Member` a bunch of times.